# Where Debug info stored in Framework?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, lldb

As the title mentioned, I'm confusing about where is the debug info stored in `.Framework` file.

I googled for serval days, what I gots are:

> Framework binary compiled by debug mode will include a debug info segment, to indicate the symbol location. Release mode compiling will move it to a dSYM file.

But, what confused me is, I build a framework with ninja, and it doesn't generate `dSYM` file. Meanwhile I can't find the symbol location by `dwarfdump` command or `MachOView` app. As Regards `strings` command can get some relative file path results, like `../../flutter/fml/memory/task_runner_checker.cc`.

Here dwarfdump prints:

```
Flutter.framework/Flutter:      file format Mach-O arm64

.debug_info contents:
```

Here is my questions:

1. When I triggered breakpoint at somewhere in the framework, the source code still shows. Why?
2. When I run lldb command, it shows:

```
(lldb) image lookup -a $pc --verbose
      Address: Flutter[0x0000000001964f18] (Flutter.__TEXT.__text + 26604184)
      Summary: Flutter`dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_LoadLibraryFromTypedData(dart::Thread*, dart::Zone*, dart::NativeArguments*) + 44 [inlined] dart::NativeArguments::NativeArgAt(int) const at object.cc:537
               Flutter`dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_LoadLibraryFromTypedData(dart::Thread*, dart::Zone*, dart::NativeArguments*) + 44 [inlined] dart::DN_HelperLoadLibraryFromTypedData(dart::Isolate*, dart::Thread*, dart::Zone*, dart::NativeArguments*) at object.cc:534
               Flutter`dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_LoadLibraryFromTypedData(dart::Thread*, dart::Zone*, dart::NativeArguments*) + 44 at object.cc:534
       Module: file = "/Users/xx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-ddigzjlnuypwnydlawevfrkmdsov/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XXX.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter", arch = "arm64"
  CompileUnit: id = {0x00000000}, file = "/Users/xx/Documents/workspace/aion/flutter_engine/src/third_party/dart/runtime/lib/object.cc", language = "c++14"
     Function: id = {0x7d40006244d}, name = "dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_LoadLibraryFromTypedData(dart::Thread*, dart::Zone*, dart::NativeArguments*)", mangled = "_ZN4dart16BootstrapNatives27DN_LoadLibraryFromTypedDataEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_4ZoneEPNS_15NativeArgumentsE", range = [0x0000000117310eec-0x0000000117311490)
     FuncType: id = {0x7d40006244d}, byte-size = 0, decl = bootstrap_natives.h:507, compiler_type = "class dart::ObjectPtr (class dart::Thread *, class dart::Zone *, class dart::NativeArguments *)"
       Blocks: id = {0x7d40006244d}, range = [0x117310eec-0x117311490)
               id = {0x7d40006249b}, ranges = [0x117310f18-0x1173113e0)[0x117311404-0x117311490), name = "DN_HelperLoadLibraryFromTypedData", decl = object.cc:534, mangled = _ZN4dartL33DN_HelperLoadLibraryFromTypedDataEPNS_7IsolateEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_4ZoneEPNS_15NativeArgumentsE, demangled = dart::DN_HelperLoadLibraryFromTypedData(dart::Isolate*, dart::Thread*, dart::Zone*, dart::NativeArguments*)
               id = {0x7d40006253a}, range = [0x117310f18-0x117310f24), name = "NativeArgAt", decl = native_arguments.h:129, mangled = _ZNK4dart15NativeArguments11NativeArgAtEi, demangled = dart::NativeArguments::NativeArgAt(int) const
    LineEntry: [0x0000000117310f18-0x0000000117310f24): /Users/xx/Documents/workspace/xxx/flutter_engine/src/third_party/dart/runtime/vm/native_arguments.h:132:14
       Symbol: id = {0x0013fd0f}, range = [0x0000000117310eec-0x0000000117311490), name="dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_LoadLibraryFromTypedData(dart::Thread*, dart::Zone*, dart::NativeArguments*)", mangled="_ZN4dart16BootstrapNatives27DN_LoadLibraryFromTypedDataEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_4ZoneEPNS_15NativeArgumentsE"
     Variable: id = {0x7d400062553}, name = "this", type = "const dart::NativeArguments *", location = DW_OP_reg20 W20, decl = 
     Variable: id = {0x7d40006255c}, name = "index", type = "int", location = <decoding error> 00 00 00, decl = native_arguments.h:129
     Variable: id = {0x7d4000624a8}, name = "isolate", type = "dart::Isolate *", location = , decl = object.cc:534
     Variable: id = {0x7d4000624ad}, name = "thread", type = "dart::Thread *", location = , decl = object.cc:534
     Variable: id = {0x7d4000624b2}, name = "zone", type = "dart::Zone *", location = DW_OP_reg19 W19, decl = object.cc:534
     Variable: id = {0x7d4000624bb}, name = "arguments", type = "dart::NativeArguments *", location = DW_OP_reg20 W20, decl = object.cc:534
     Variable: id = {0x7d4000624c4}, name = "program", type = "unique_ptr<dart::xx_kernel::Program, std::__1::default_delete<dart::xx_kernel::Program> >", location = DW_OP_breg31 WSP+64, decl = object.cc:556
     Variable: id = {0x7d400062468}, name = "thread", type = "dart::Thread *", location = DW_OP_reg24 W24, decl = object.cc:534
     Variable: id = {0x7d400062479}, name = "zone", type = "dart::Zone *", location = DW_OP_reg19 W19, decl = object.cc:534
     Variable: id = {0x7d40006248a}, name = "arguments", type = "dart::NativeArguments *", location = DW_OP_reg20 W20, decl = object.cc:534
```

So, where the lldb get `Compile Unit` and `LineEntry` outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug information on Darwin systems exists in one of two places:  In the `.o` files, and later after `dsymutil` is run to create a `.dSYM`, it exists in the `.dSYM` bundle, all collected together, relocated to the actual binary's addresses.

This was a build-link-debug performance enhancement.  Linking all of the debug information -- updating all the symbol addresses, copying it all around -- is very slow, so leaving the debug information in the `.o` files for this common iterative development cycle, and having the debugger locate the `.o` files and update the addresses of the functions internally, allows for rapid development.

Leaving all of the debug information in the `.o` files requires that they all be present, of course!  And at the same file paths.  So it is not good when you need to move a binary between computers, or save it for later debugging.  For these cases, you link the debug information with `dsymutil` and you get a `.dSYM` bundle.

Comment: Thanks for you help very much. Now I Can understand why `dwarfdump BINARYFILE` prints no debug info. But, another question comes after. Sometimes we don't have dSYM file, how could the binary file find where the debug info located? Just like I mentioned in my question, lldb command prints `Compile Unit` that indicates where related file is. Thanks again.

Comment: @RyanYan if you use `nm -pa BINARYFILE`, you will see old stabs list entries that we call a "debug map" - they include pointers to the `.o` file paths (the `OSO` entries) in addition to the start/end of source files, functions, and global symbols.  dsymutil or lldb use these debug map entries in an unstripped executable to "relocate" the DWARF from the `.o` files to their correct, linked, addresses.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm really appreciate your help